# sql - Find the ID of the most booked flight

Tags: sql

In the `booking` table I'm using, the fields are `FlightNo, CustomerNo, DateOfFlight, DateBooked`

I'm trying to find the flight number of the most booked flight. I have `5` bookings for `flight101` and `2` for `flight105` but the below code is returning `flight105` as the result.

```
SELECT distinct(flightNo)
FROM booking
WHERE flightNo IN
(SELECT max(flightNo) AS maximum FROM booking);
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, it's a part of SELECT DISTINCT, and it works on the whole selected rows. select distinct (c1), c2... eq. select distinct c1, c2... eq. select distinct c1, (c2)...

Comment: please update your question with the specific database your using, @jarlh is correct in the comment provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use a group by to fix

```
select flightNo, count(*) from booking group by flightNo
```

Here you are grouping the results to flightNo and counting all the records given this flightNo. If you want to only display 1 record the most booked flight order it by `count(*)` desc and limit the results to 1.

```
select flightNo, count(*) from booking group by flightNo order by count(*) desc limit 1
```

Comment: LIMIT is product specific, but for which dbms? (No dbms specified in question...)

Comment: To show more then 1 he could simply do 
`select flightNo, count(*) from booking group by flightNo order by count(*) desc`
leaving the limit out of the query.